# Using chained promises ($q) to make $http

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have data that I want to be "reverify". So I need to make a get request, save the data from the callback, delete the current data, then make a post with the data from the callback.

I need to use $q somehow.

Maybe I'm totally off but here's what i tried.

```
$scope.reSaveBIM = function(){

  var defer = $q.defer();

  defer.promise
    .then(function(){
      $http.get('/api/bim/' + $scope.activePartOfBim._id)
        .success(function(fullBIM){
          console.log(fullBIM); //Defined
          return fullBIM;
        }
      );
    })
    .then(function(fullBIM){
      console.log(fullBIM); //Undefined
      $http.delete('/api/bim/' + $scope.activePartOfBim._id);
      return fullBIM
    })
    .then(function(fullBIM){
      $http.post('/api/bim', {bim:JSON.stringify(fullBIM)});
    });

  defer.resolve()

};
```

The data from the first callback is not returned in the chained. Am I on the right track? I also tried to use $q.all but failed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create an additional `$q.defer` object, you can simply chain the promise returned by `$http`...

```
$scope.reSaveBIM = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/bim/' + $scope.activePartOfBim._id).then(function(response) {
        var fullBIM = response.data;
        return fullBIM;
    }).then(function(fullBIM) {
        return $http.delete('/api/bim/' + $scope.activePartOfBim._id).then(function() {
            return fullBIM;
        });
    }).then(function(fullBIM) {
        return $http.post('/api/bim', { bim:JSON.stringify(fullBIM) }).then(function() {
            return fullBIM;
        });
    }).catch(function(response) {
        // return an error message using throw
        throw "Something went wrong - Status " + response.status;
    });
};
```

To call it...

```
$scope.reSaveBIM().then(function(fullBIM) {
    console.log('success! fullBIM: ', fullBIM);
}, function(errorMsg) {
    console.log(errorMsg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS's $http already wraps the $q service.  [From the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the $q service.

Essentially your problem is that $http uses a different promise than the one you are creating with $q.  You need chain your $http calls to do the same thing.  The fact is, you are already using promises from $q.

Furthermore, you can flatten this out by declaring functions and passing them in as variables.

```
$http.get('/api/bim/' + $scope.activePartOfBim._id)
    .success(firstSuccessFunction);

var firstResponse;
var firstSuccessFunction = function(fullBIM){
  console.log(fullBIM); //Defined
  firstResponse= fullBIM;
  $http.delete('/api/bim/' + $scope.activePartOfBim._id)
          .success(secondSuccessFunction);
};

var secondSuccessFunction = function(deleteResponse) {
  $http.post('/api/bim', {bim:JSON.stringify(firstResponse)});
};
```

Comment: Of Course I could build a pyramid but I want to learn to flatten it out with the promises.

Comment: $http already operates on promises.  .success() is equivalent to .then().  If you want to flatten out your code then you should not inline your response functions.  Try passing a function as a parameter to the success method i.e. .success(mySuccessFunction);

Comment: There's a subtle problem... `firstSuccessFunction` is `undefined` when it is passed to `.success(firstSuccessFunction)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right, and you don't need `defer`. Instead of `success` use `then`. I think success does not return promise. Also $http `then` success callback has `data` in `response.data` property.